# Vanilla JavaScript can't add image with set src (image not loaded)

Tags: javascript, image

I search to load an image with JS, I know his path, and I would like the source of the image to be added dynamically.

I have no error in the console and the image is displayed after removing the display to none but remains a browser icon.

The image source is being updated. But not displayed. If I right clic on browser icon, and I reload the image, it's works.

[image]

My code:

```
<div id="result" style="display: none;">
    <img src="" alt="" id="myImage">
</div>

<script>
var path = '/assets/image.png';
var result = document.querySelector('#result');
var image = document.querySelector('img#myImage');
image.src = path;
result.style = 'display: block;';
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure it’s selecting the right `img` element? Maybe you want `result.querySelector('img')` instead?

Comment: Or give the `<img>` an ID so you can select it that way.

Comment: Use the Elements viewer in DevTools to see if the `src` is being updated.

Comment: you  are probably missing something in your path. Try to access your image on your host/relativepath by providing it in the url field and see if really appears,

Comment: It works, I found the correct tag, but the image is not displayed ...

Comment: @Barmar Yes, the image source is being updated. But not displayed. If I right clic on browser icon, and I reload the image, it's works.

Comment: Then it sounds like you're using the wrong URL to the image source.